# How Do I Diasble the Back Button in An Android App

Tags: android, android-layout

in my app to from one activity to other just like A->B->C or C->A i have placed buttons because the operations of the app are like that. So there is no need for the default back button of android. If the user wrongly clicks there should not be any operation done. For this how to disable the back button in device?

Comment: Disabling back is not reccommended. If your app has such a complex activity flow, you might want to use `Fragment`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

Override the `onBackPressed` method and do nothing:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way of handling it, but please don't do this. Your users should always be able to return to where they left off. You should reconsider what you're trying to accomplish before restricting how your user may interact with his device.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do nothing in your overriden onBackPressed()

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

or

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: actually i tried this method but not work please tell me another answer

Comment: Maybe because your code is not hitting onBack.try my updated code

Answer (score 0):

this will help you

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    return false;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```